# Convert "while" loop to "for" and "do while"

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

Looking to convert the following code that adds values of integers from a "while" loop to a "for" and a "do while". I managed to get it working correctly with the "for" and the "while" loop but when I try and convert the same loop into a "do while" I'm getting some weird numbers

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountLoop{
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    int i = -1;
    int limit = 0;
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    String end1 = in.nextLine();
    int end = Integer.parseInt(end1);



    /*while (i < end){
        i++;
        limit = (i + limit); 
        */


    //for (i = -1; i < end; limit = (i + limit)) i++;{ 

    do {
        limit = (i + limit);
        i++;

    } while ((i < end)); 
    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in between 0 and " + end + " is i = " + limit);




    }
    //System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in between 0 and " + end + " is i = " + limit);
}
```

Like I said, the "while" and the "for" loops work correctly so I commented them out to focus on the "do while" loop, which is giving me close, but incorrect values for the output. For example, when I put 100, the expected answer is 5050 but I get 4949 for whatever reason. I tried to change around the initial values of the variables and doing things like adding "end" back into it but that makes everything worse. Not sure what I did wrong here but any help is appreciated.

Comment: The do...while statement creates a loop that executes a specified statement until the test condition evaluates to false. The condition is evaluated after executing the statement, resulting in the specified statement executing at least once.

Comment: if the while loop does work to you, do it the same way:
`i++;`
`limit = (i + limit)`

And why does your while in your do-while have two parentheses? I doubt I has anything to do here, but leave it like `while (i < end)` instead

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is incrementing `i` before it's added to the result. That means that the loop condition `while (i < end)` will cause the loop to exit when `i` is equal to the `end` value, but the end value will already be added to the total, on the last iteration.

To get the same behavior in the `do while` loop, change the end condition to `<=`.

```
do {
    limit = (i + limit);
    i++;

} while (i <= end);
```

Also, change the initial value of `i` to 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to swap your lines as below :

```
do {
    i++;
    limit = (i + limit);
} while ((i < end));
```

So your `do while` will be the same as your initial `while`.

Answer (score 0):

I think `while` and `do while` both will act the same way in this case.  Try this

```
do {
    i++;
    limit = (i + limit);

} while ((i < end)); 
System.out.println("The sum of the numbers in between 0 and " + end + " is i = " + limit);
```